# How to use addkml method of gmap4rails gem to draw region boundaries for New York city?

Tags: google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

when i search through zip-code, i want to draw boundaries like this http://www.apartments.com/new-york-ny-10128/ or http://streeteasy.com/for-sale/battery-park-city

I am using below code for testing purpose but this isn't working. URL link doesn't exist any more.

```
var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ internal: {id: 'with_kml'}}, function(){
  var kmls = handler.addKml(
    { url: "http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml" }
  );
})
```

Currently i am using gmaps4rails gem to add markers so is it possible to add region boundaries using gmaps4rails ?

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Kml) that show how to display KML using Google-Maps-for-Rails.

```
<%= gmaps( :kml => {:data => '[{ url: "http://www.searcharoo.net/SearchKml/newyork.kml"}, 
{ url: "http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml",
options: {clickable: false } }]' } ) %>
```

For more information about gmaps4rails, check these github:

- [Gmaps4rails](https://apneadiving.github.io/)
- [apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails)

Comment: Thank you KENdi , i'll try this.